# Problema al cargar un archivo .fxml

Tags: javafx

Estoy empezando a trabajar con *JavaFX* pero cuando intento mostrar mi archivo `.fxml` me manda el siguiente error:

> ```
> javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
> /C:/Users/Javier/eclipse-workspace/Hola/bin/application/Form.fxml:11
>
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:922)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
>   at application.Main.start(Main.java:15)
>   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyController
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:920)
>   ... 22 more
> ```

Esta es mi estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Clase Main:

```
    public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Form.fxml"));
            Scene esena = new Scene(root);
            
            primaryStage.setScene(esena);
            primaryStage.show();
        
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class MyController implements Initializable{

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar.

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes añadir el contenido del .fxml? Sería también de ayuda. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Yo siempre los empiezo asi

```
    FXMLLoader f = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/NuevoDialog.fxml"));
    f.setController(this);
    Parent root = f.load();
    Scene sc = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(sc);
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Problemas posibles:

**1. El fichero fxml no esta correctamente enlazado con su controlador.**

Ocurre a veces cuando hacemos cambios en la estructura (si antes funcionaba). 
Si el fichero fxml a cargar se indica a la clase que lo está cargando con la línea:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Form.fxml"));
```

dentro de este fichero esta indicado a su vez donde se encuentra el controlador correspondiente, esto lo vas a tener el la línea 11:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Javier/eclipse-workspace/Hola/bin/application/Form.fxml:11
```

esta línea dentro del contenedor de tu ventana, generalmente un AnchorPane, debe tener la ruta del controlador correctamente indicada, con el paquete y nombre de la clase (buscalos en la clase del controlador):

```
fx:controller="application.MyController">
```